# ODE Non linear Non separable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \frac{dy} {dx} = \frac{3x-4y-2}{3x-4y-3}$$

I don't know how to solve this. Searched about the equation to know about the non separable one. I know about the separable one. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: did you try to substitute $z=4y-3x $ or $z=3x-4y-3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{3x-4y-2}{3x-4y-3}.....(1)$

Take $t=3x-4y-2$

$$\dfrac{dt}{dx}=3-4\dfrac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{3-4\dfrac{dy}{dx}}{4}$$

$$3-\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\dfrac{4t}{t-1}$$

$$\dfrac{1-t}{t+3}dt=dx$$

$$\int\dfrac{1-t}{t+3}dt=\int dx$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: But how its different from the previous one?

Comment: @jayant98 what previous one?

Comment: From the question.

Comment: @Flex yes I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

With the Substitution $$z=4y-3x$$ we get
$$y'=\frac{z'+3}{4}$$ and $z'$ is equal to
$$z'=\frac{z-1}{z+3}$$

Comment: Ok. From here I can do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you suggest me any good material on it for reading ? (This topic)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy} {dx} = \frac{3x-4y-2}{3x-4y-3}$$
$$\frac{dy}{3x-4y-2}  = \frac  {dx}{3x-4y-3}$$
$$\frac{d(3x-4y)}{-3x+4y-1}  = \frac  {d(y-x)}{1}$$
After integration 
$$ -\ln (3x-4y+1)=(y-x)+C$$
Finally
$$\boxed {(y-x)+\ln (3x-4y+1)=K}$$